# De programación estructurada a programación orientada a objetos - PHP

Tags: php, poo

Estoy intentando actualizar mi forma de programar de Programación Estructurada (no se si relamente se llame asi. pero es un poco desordenada) a Programación Orientada a Objetos. He estado viendo la programación orientada a objetos en el ultimo mes y tengo la siguiente duda cuando creo un Objeto de tipo Usuario

```html
<?php

class usuario{

    private $usuarioId;
    private $usuario;
    private $password;
    private $rolId;
    private $estado;
    private $fc;
    private $fm;


    function __construct($usuarioId,$usuario,$password,$rolId,$estado,$fc,$fm){
        $this->usuarioId = $usuarioId;
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->rolId = $rolId;
        $this->estado = $estado;
        $this->fc = $fc;
        $this->fm = $fm;
    }

    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->password  = $password;
    }
    public function getPassword(){
        return $password;
    }
}


?>
```

1. Es necesario crear un metodo `set` y `get` para cada atributo o existe
   algún tipo de atajo(una forma de crear un método único para ello)?

Comment: Al ser atributos privados tienes que crear todos los getters y setters.
De todas formas, algunos IDEs como Eclipse tienen una opción para que te los genere y no los tengas que escribir tu.

Comment: No te hace falta escribir todos. Con usar los métodos mágicos vale.

Comment: Te recomiendo este post de POO https://thenullpointerexceptionx.blogspot.com/2019/07/programacion-orientada-objetos.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar lo que se llaman los métodos mágicos de PHP

```
<?php

class usuario{

    private $usuarioId;
    private $usuario;
    private $password;
    private $rolId;
    private $estado;
    private $fc;
    private $fm;


    function __construct($usuarioId,$usuario,$password,$rolId,$estado,$fc,$fm){
        $this->usuarioId = $usuarioId;
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->rolId = $rolId;
        $this->estado = $estado;
        $this->fc = $fc;
        $this->fm = $fm;
    }

    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}


?>
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter)
[Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Comment: Eso exactamente es lo que buscaba. solo para documentar un poco mas
instancia el objeto `$usuario = new usuario("user001","123","1","Activo","","");`
utilizar la propiedad __get `echo $usuario->nombredelatributo` utilizar la propiedad __set `echo $usuario->nombredelatrubuto = "valor";`